# Get id of selected item of ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

This is my ListView :

```
 <ListView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemTapped="itemTapped" x:Name="listofEmployee" BackgroundColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.listBackgroundColor}" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="imgCheckUncheck" Source="btn_check_off.png" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" >
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImg_TapGestureRecognizerTapped" />  
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding empName}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.listTextColor}" />                               
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Model for this :

```
public  class empList_Model
{
    public string empName{ get; set;}
    public int Selected{ get; set;}
    public string id{ get; set;}
}
public static class empList_Data
{
    public static List<empList_Model> getData ()
    {
        return new List<empList_Model> {

            new empList_Model () {
                empName = "Bryan Garret",Selected=0,id="1"
            },

            new empList_Model () {
                empName = "James Simpson",Selected=0,id="2",
            },

            new empList_Model () {
                empName = "Kathryn Newer",Selected=0,id="3"
            },

            new empList_Model () {
                empName = "Amanda Stevens",Selected=0,id="4"
            },

        };
    }
}
```

By using above code I want to take some actions as below :

1)On image tap, set property selected=1 or selected=0 of class empList_Model.

2)On image tap, display property "id" in DisplayAlert() function.

Comment: I am missing the "itemTapped" implementation in your code snippets above. This needs to be handled there.

Comment: Exactly! I am not getting what to do inside "itemTapped" event. Generally I was trying to access selected item by using sender of event method but its showing me "Projectname.empList_Model" for every item.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the "itemTapped" event in the code behind class as there is no command binding to the view model possible. This should look like this:

```
public void OmItemTapped (object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataItem = e.Item as empList_Model;
        // now you can change the data item or trigger anything on the
        // view model and provide the tapped instance as parameter
    }
```